# How do you select the value for the latest date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to simply select the value which has the latest timestamp, but for some reason I'm having some sort of brain freeze.

The code below is selecting all the records:

```
SELECT S.idindicator, S.val ,[Time] = MAX(CAST(S.valTimestamp as date)), S.valTimestamp
FROM Status as S
WHERE S.INVALID = 0 
    AND S.id = 16888
GROUP by S.idindicator, S.val, S.valTimestamp 
ORDER BY S.valTimestamp DESC
```

[image]

How do I simply just select the `val` which has the latest date, which is 75.00?

Note: I have done it using a correlated subquery, however, it turns it into an expensive query.

Comment: `SELECT TOP 1 S.val FROM ...`

Comment: you wont be able to use ORDER BY because `SELECT TOP 1 FROM (` will turn it into a subquery, if i'm not mistaken

Comment: @user3396351 Did you try it?

Comment: yes I tried it and ORDER BY cannot be used in subqueries

Comment: `SELECT TOP <n>` return the first n row. You want only the first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want just one row, use `top (1)` and `order by`:

```
select top (1) *
from status s
where invalid = 0 and id = 16888
order by valTimestamp desc
```

If you want the same result over multiple `id`s, then one option uses window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select s.*, row_number() over(partition by id order by valTimestamp desc) rn
    from status s
    where invalid = 0
) s
where rn = 1
```

If you want to allow ties, then you would use `top (1) with ties` in the first query, and `rank()` instead of `row_number()` in the second query.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for something as simple as :

```
SELECT TOP 1 S.idindicator, S.val , S.valTimestamp
FROM Status as S
WHERE S.INVALID = 0 AND S.id = 16888
GROUP by S.idindicator, S.val, S.valTimestamp 
ORDER BY S.valTimestamp DESC
```

EDIT : As pointed in comment, limit doesn't exist in t-sql, use top 1 instead

Comment: `LIMIT` isn't a T-SQL operator; it uses `TOP`.